# Creating controls on runtime - pass data

Tags: c#, .net, events, dynamic, controls

In Windows Forms project I have this method to set some properties of dynamically created control. In this case I also need to show a tooltip when user hovers mouse over it. This works ok except for one thing, I have no idea how to pass the value of w["text"] to control_MouseEnter.

```
private void SetProp(ref Control obiekt, Dictionary<string, string> w)
    {
        obiekt.Name = w["id"];
        obiekt.Location = new Point(Convert.ToInt16(w["wspx"]), Convert.ToInt16(w["wspy"]));
        obiekt.Height = Convert.ToInt16(w["wys"]);
        obiekt.Width = Convert.ToInt16(w["szer"]);
        if (w["text"] != "")
        {
            obiekt.MouseEnter += new EventHandler(control_MouseEnter);
            obiekt.MouseLeave += new EventHandler(control_MoouseLeave);
        }
    }

private void control_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        toolTip.Show("how to pass a value here ??", (Control)sender, 5000);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have no idea has to pass the value of w["text"] to control_MouseEnter.

You can either link your data with target control directly (for example via Control.Tag property) or indirectly (for example, via global variable/dictionary), or use anonymous delegate and closure to create the local data-context:

```
obiekt.MouseEnter += (s,e) => { 
    tooltip.Show(w["text"], (Control)s, 5000);
};
```

> Is there a way to use EventArgs somehow?

No, you can't. Because the args are instantiated within the Control's code exactly at the moment when the mouse event occurs, and you can't control the EventArgs creation from event-subscription point.

Comment: This seems a nice solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

How about setting the text into `Tag` member of `Control` object?

S.th. like `object.Tag = w["text"];` and show it with event handler

Comment: Thank you, this in fact works as expected. Is that the only solution ? Is there a way to use EventArgs somehow ?